# Python Sudoku Puzzle 9 x 9 Checker

Tags: python

```
while True:
    try:
        file = input("Enter a filename: ") 
        fi = open(file, "r")
        infile = fi.read()
        grid = [list (i) for i in infile.split()] #Puts the sudoku puzzle into a list in     order to check that the total number is valid
        check = len(grid)
        print("The total number in this puzzle is:",check) #Counts the amount of numbers in the sudoku puzzle
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print ("The inputted file does not exist")

def check(infile):
    count = 0
    for j in range (0,9):
        for n in range(0,9):
            if infile[j].count(infile[j][n]) <= 1:
                count = count + 0
            else:
                count = count + 1
```

This is my current code for a sudoku checker, will someone please tell me what is wrong with it, because I am trying to find out if all the numbers in the columns are between 1 and 9

Answer (score 1):

You never explicitly call the function `check` in this code.

Comment: I suspect there's more to it than that. infile should probably be grid. Some other things too.